# Ubuntu - How to automount an external drive at a preconfigured mount point?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, external-hard-drive, mount, usb-flash-drive

Normally, when I attach an external USB drive to my Ubuntu system, the filesystem on it are automounted to /media/**label**. However, I'd like the filesystem to be mounted at a mount point of my choosing. I've added a line like this to my */etc/fstab*:

```
UUID=2BE905C238C1F724   /p   ntfs-3g   defaults   0   0   # Passport 320GB
```

This allows me to manually mount the volume at */p* by running *sudo mount /p*, however the filesystem is no longer automounted when the drive is attached to the PC. What do I need to do to get automount to this mount point to work, if at all possible?

Comment: This is not a real answer, more like a workaround: If the label is unique among your media, you could make /p a symlink to /media/label.

Comment: I've always had terrible luck with external USB drives and Ubuntu. They never seem to mount in the right place - so I did the same thing as balpha.

Comment: It seems like it should be possible to override this, at least for compliant volume managers, by arranging for the `volume.mount_point` HAL property to be set.  I have not, however, figured out how to accomplish this or make it work with Thunar's volume manager.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GeorgeM is close, but not close enough.

On Ubuntu, `gnome-mount` is reponsible for mounting media and also for maintaining the needed configuration. The [man page of gnome-mount](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gnome-mount) should tell you much more and with a little trial and error you should be able to achieve what you want.

After I played with this for a little while, I found the following:

1. It seems you can **not** specifiy a mount point outside of `/media`
2. You can set the mount points name by hal udi

The following command will change the settings used to mount a USB drive on my system:

```
gnome-mount --write-settings \
            --hal-udi /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/volume_uuid_00AD_15D0 
            --mount-point p
```

When inserted, the USB drive will be mounted in `/media/p`

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark this as the accepted answer, unless someone comes up with a way to achieve mounts outside */media*.

Answer (score 1):

The mount point is determined by HAL and its complicated and arcane rules. No need to hack your fstab file.

Answer (score 0):

For an external USB hard-disk formatted with ext4 (you'll need to adapt the options if using ntfs):

- created a file `99-toshiba.rules`:

  ```
  IMPORT{program}="/sbin/blkid -o udev -p %N"
  ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}!="toshiba", GOTO="toshiba_end"
  ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mkdir -m 0 -p /media/toshiba", RUN+="/bin/mount -o noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro /dev/%k /media/toshiba"
  ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/bin/umount -l /dev/%k", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /home/toshiba"
  LABEL="toshiba_end"
  ```
- copied the file: `sudo cp 99-toshiba.rules /lib/udev/rules.d/`
- reloaded the configuration `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`

As you can see the I manually set the mount point to `/media/toshiba` but it could be anywhere.

it actually works ;-)