# Linux fstab mounting

Tags: linux, mount, removable

I'm trying to get fstab to auto-mount a removable device when its plugged in? Is this possible and if not what is the easiest way to auto-mount a removable device?

Comment: related automounting questions: http://superuser.com/questions/16823/ubuntu-how-to-automount-an-external-drive-at-a-preconfigured-mount-point .. http://superuser.com/questions/53978/ubuntu-automatically-mount-external-drives-to-media-label-on-boot-without-a-us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need some kind of automounter.  That will largely depend on what Linux distribution you have and whether or not you're using a GUI or CLI based system.  And then, it will also depend on whether or not your using Gnome or KDE as your desktop environment.  My experience lies with Gnome on Gentoo, Ubuntu and a little experience with Redhat.  But you won't be able to use fstab to automatically mount devices when they're plugged in or removed.

Comment: this is correct; /etc/fstab is not used for automounting hotplugged devices.

Answer (score 1):

While you many not be able to use fstab, you will be able to set up automount with [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) and [hal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL_(software)). However, in my experience (KDE, Gnome, and XCFE) Desktop Environments will automatically mount most removable devices.

Comment: i posted a lengthy how-to-automount-with-udev answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/53978/ubuntu-automatically-mount-external-drives-to-media-label-on-boot-without-a-us/64970#64970 .. there's also a HAL-based solution with HALevt in another answer below that one.  you're right that most desktop environments provide their own automounter.